# Incoming Email setup in MOSS

Tags: sharepoint

I have setup incoming Email on my first WEF and it looks like it is working OK and I don't see any error messages. However, I have added a second WEF and I see error messages in Event Logs on the second WEF about incoming email.
A critical error occurred while processing the incoming e-mail drop folder . The error was: Value cannot be null.

I am guessing it has got to do with the drop folder. The drop folder on the first WEF which the SMTP Service is running is poiting to the C drive. Is it because the second WEF doesn't have access to that foler? if so, what is the best way to set it up?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give some more information about your setup? Specifically, the central admin incoming email settings, and where the MX record is pointing (at your load balancer or at the first WFE server).

Answer (score 1):

Actually all you need to do is create a drop folder on your 2nd front end on the C drive - whatever path it is looking for.  I've seen this before - and it's remedied by just creating a drop folder where it says it needs to be.  Don't try to share the drop folder from WFE #1 - they operate independently - and #2 just needs to be set up like #1.

Comment: One of the key points to MOSS WFEs is that all paths must be the same and exist on all WFEs otherwise you'll see errors or things may not work as expected. As noted, you won't use the drop folder on WFE2, but it needs to exist otherwise MOSS will complain.